# Docker-compose UP Throwing moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 not found

Tags: docker-compose

While I'm building a docker-compose yml file for the first time having multiple docker images I'm getting below error message. I know that I'm not using moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 image - I think it something as intermediate or internal used while building docker-compose

I had configured "experimental": true to config.json and deamon.json but it didn't help

Here is the data files

```
$cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
     context: ./server

$cat ./server/Dockerfile
From node:alpine
```

Error message:
[image]

But when I directly mention image name 'node:alpine' in docker-compose.yml it runs fine.

I tried looking for a solution on articles but didn't help much - could you please help me here?

Comment: Could you, please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75843785/edit) the question and share your `docker-compose.yml`, it will help others to find solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi @WerWet I've added more data now. Thank you

Comment: Everything looks fine. There seems to be a problem with the docker itself, because the buildkit is its build engine. Can you build the `Dockerfile` with the `docker build` command?

Comment: @WerWet I am able to 'docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t image_node .' successfully.

Comment: That's odd, I would then try to reset any configs, and/or reinstall the docker